# Ruby OpenSSL AES generate random key

Tags: ruby, openssl, key, aes, encryption

I have an elementary problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to generate a random key in AES-256-CBC that can be used to encrypt/decrypt data.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
require 'openssl'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
cipher.encrypt
puts cipher.random_key
>> "\xACOM:\xCF\xB3@o)<&y!\x16A\xA1\xB5m?\xF1 \xC9\x1F>\xDB[Uhz)\v0"
```

That gives me the string above, which looks nothing like keys i've used in the past. I am very new to encryption as you may be able to tell, but I'm trying to understand if I need to further prepare the string. I created a quick view in rails so I could go to /generate and it would render a simple html page with a random key. It wouldn't even render the page and was complaining about invalid uTF8. the only way I could get the page to display was to Base64 encode the key first.

I know i'm missing something stupid. Any ideas would be great.

EDIT:
This is what it looks like if I Base64encode. Should I be stripping the = signs off or something?

```
AES-128-CBC
Random Key: 0xdq+IZdmYHHbLC9Uv8jgQ== 
Random IV: vp08d/nFGE3R8HsmOzYzOA==

AES-256-CBC
Random Key: BW0wY5fUkcwszV5GIczI+D45eFOz/Ehvw5XdZIavVOQ= 
Random IV: D0pXdwQAqu+XSOv8E/dqBw==
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why would you display the encryption key on a web page of all things? Base64 is fine if you need to safely round trip the key.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution, and the page is only in development, not published. Besides each time you render the page, a random key is generated, nothing that anyone can do with that other than maybe see what encryption library i'm using. I'm just trying to generate a key! Base64 is adding two equal signs to the end of the key. Do I include those in the key that I will be using? or do I strip those off? The other keys that i've used (which have been generated for me) have never included equal signs on the end. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The key is your initial raw byte sequence. You base64 encode it to avoid problems in transferring it. Don't touch the =. It's part of the string. To use the key, you will have to reverse the encoding i.e. decode the base64.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That is starting to make a little bit of sense. The trouble i'm having is that a key that was generated by a 3rd party partner is just usable from the get go. I do not have to first decode it or anything. How can I generate a key like that to just email a partner and they can plug it into their aes method and it will just work? Thanks again

Comment: I had the same issue, when tried to store random key in AES-256-EBC in database. Thanks to your commends I've found a solution - encode it with Base64, then store it in DB and decode, when it needed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (quoted from Wikipedia):

> The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one
>   byte, and '=' indicates that it contained two bytes.
>
> In theory, the padding character is not needed for decoding, since the
>   number of missing bytes can be calculated from the number of Base64
>   digits. In some implementations, the padding character is mandatory,
>   while for others it is not used.

For Ruby and your use case the answer is: No problem to strip the `=`